# put condition of time when a client disconnects to a socket server

Tags: socket.io

Hi everyone as a beginner in WebSockets i want to put a condition  that will query when a client will be online or offline for such a time on my server node.js using socket.io

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        db.query("MY_SQL_REQUEST");
      });
```

As a example when the user is disconnected for 10secondes it does the request. I think the solution is to use a loop if, but i dont know how to process after ...

If you need more informations about my code dont hesitate to ask

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. when user online then you can store socket id in specific user.
> 2. when user disconnect then automatically call socket disconnect event and you will get disconnected socket id. once you receive socket id
>      you can update query for user offline using disconnected socket id.

```
socket.on('disconnect',function(){
    console.log("socket disconnect called: ",socket.id);
    db.query("MY_SQL_REQUEST"); // where socketId = socket.id
})
```